# Android Studio: Put menu buttons on the left in material design

Tags: android, menu

I will start the topic by saying that I didn't see any question like mine.

So, my question is:  I have a simple application to practice the material design layout style and I want to have a menu button on the left, to be able to go backwards. This is the code of the menu. I don't think that someone needs more than that:

```
menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/navigate"
    android:title="@string/next"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Comment: *I don't think that someone would need more* ... i need ... image ... left back button can be added without menu if you are using toolbar as actionbar ... menu items on ltr device will alway be on the right side ... just take a look at any official appcompat sample with navigationdrawer ... I'm pretty sure that you will find there what you need

Comment: By saying that i am using material design, i am saying that i am using toolbar. More, why would u need the image if u can give an example like: image="your_image"

Comment: because I'm not sure if you at least tried to read trainings on developer.android.com ... where @+id/navigate should be placed on the toolbar/actionbar? ... at the place where normal actionbar has "navigate up" button ? then what for? if you turn it on(it is explained well in the docs) you need your own menu button ...